# Building a real time stock quotes application? (lots of XMLHttpRequest?)

Tags: javascript, websocket

I'm creating a personal application which displays stock quotes realtime (updating every second), and I was wondering what was the best way to approach this project?

I'm going to query using Yahoo YQL: [example query.](https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2a%20from%20yahoo.finance.quote%20where%20symbol%20in%20%28%22AAPL%22%2C%22GOOG%22%2C%22MSFT%22%29&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=)

1. I've been researching `WebSockets` and sockets.io, but I don't believe you can use this unless you own the server with the data. Is this approach not possible?
2. Send an `XMLHttpRequest` every second? This seems really bad for some reason, just seeing all the requests in the developer tools makes me cringe and my laptop heat up.

Any thoughts? I've heard of people using an `iframe` or something to make the requests?

I cannot for the love of programming figure out how Google  and Yahoo do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An IFRAME that updates each second would have similar effect than an AJAX request every second. Some pages uses an IFRAME that refresh each X time, but there is no magic there, an IFRAME is like another browser window inside the web page.

You are right about websockets, the server must expose a websocket endpoint, otherwise is not possible. If you have this option, go for it.

There is other push technology named "Server Sent Events" (aka SSE, Event Source): http://caniuse.com/eventsource Again the server must expose it, but it basically allows the client to keep a persistent connection to the server, and this push events to the client. Again if you have this option, and websocket is not available, go for it.

If you are not in control of the server, and the only provided option is regular HTTP calls, I guess you have no other option. Please mind that some trading providers limit the amount of requests you can do per minute, or limit the amount of times the information changes per minute, so maybe doing one per second your are not achieving anything relevant... or you can get yourself banned.

Comment: Thanks, I guess it's the laptop-heating rapid xmlhttprequests then. Yeah, YQL has a pretty fair limit of how many requests you can make.

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty new to javascript and API's but I think a google or yahoo API (Application Programming Interface) would be appropriate to link the stock quotes to your app.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I know that part, my question is how to implement it into the application every second.